# Adding edit button to change report instead of using attributes in oracle APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, button, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a interactive report.

I need to change record of report on the page. But I don't want to use adding attribute that redirects to form page.

Instead of adding attribute which is symbolized  by pencil I want to add a button to page to change information because report has only one row and user change only this one row. The problem is that I add a button that redirects to the form page and I have fetch row process in after header on form page and I also add a attribute to form.

But when I click the button it redirects to the form page with no data on the form but actually there must be information from other page to change on form. When I click the attribute on report it redirects same form page with existing information on form.

How can I provide existing information on report to the form page by pressing the button on report?

Comment: Can you provide you sql query? how do you add button on your query (button rather than link). what is the action onclick on the button?

Answer (score 1):

If you define a column in your report as a type "Link", you can define your target. IR inherently has one of these.

Either way, you can set parameters to pass information, and if you use the icon next to the value, you can choose a column from the query. The syntax inserted will be in the format #COLUMN_ALIAS#.

Check out some sample applications to see how APEX pages are typically constructed.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I wıll examine the sample apps.